# Where can I find /lib/ld-lsb.so.3 for Ubuntu 21.04?

Tags: package-management, shared-library, binary, dynamic-linking

I need to get a 32 bit ELF interpreter for an old binary.

```
file ./actlmgrd 
./actlmgrd: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-lsb.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, BuildID[sha1]=74d9c7780145f113e746c1c1bccfb4d9264022bf, stripped
```

I was able to get the 64 bit variant in the lsb-core package, but I cannot find i386 equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

The answer was that ld-linux.so.2 is identical to ld-lsb.so.3.
A symbolic link solved my problem.

```
sudo ln -s /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /lib/ld-lsb.so.3
```

I now have a large supply of salty comments about Linux binary support and people who believe renaming libraries is a good idea.

Comment: Looks ok, but having such symlinks in APT controlled folder is not recommended. Placing it in /usr/local/lib  would be better. So I would recommend to use the following commands: `sudo rm /lib/ld-lsb.so.3 ; sudo ln -s /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /usr/local/lib/ld-lsb.so.3 ; sudo ldconfig` .